# Getting out integers and floats out of a String

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to get out all numbers (integers and floats) out of a given String.
For example:

```
"1.24 + 112 - 436 * 1.22 / 4 % 55"
```

I want to get `1.24` and the rest out of the string so I can do the math.
Like this:

```
[1.24,+,112,-,436,1.22,/,4,%,55]
```

Comment: Ye you want reverse polish notation. Google for some parsers to do that. Also you got `Scanner` class that can help you in parsing as well as `Integer.parseInt()` and `Float.parseFloat()`

Answer (score 0):

Here you have regular expression for

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pat=Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d++|\\d+|[-+=\\\\*/%]");
        String str="1.24+112-436*1.22/4%55";        
        Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(str);
        while(matcher.find()){
            System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
1.24
+
112
-
436
*
1.22
/
4
%
55
```

To handle negative numbers as well you will use
`Pattern.compile("-?\\d+\\.\\d++|-?\\d+|[-+=\\\\*/%]");` But there is a catch because there is no way to distict between `x-y` and `x - y` so you will have to assume that if there is no operator between 2 operands, there should be additon + resultion in `x+(-y)` and tha will be equal in both cases

But all in all, parsing math equasions can be complicated and tricky so you better use existing solution (google it out)